# Identificar si una lista de series de tiempo es igual a otra lista de series de tiempo en R

Tags: r, timeseries

Tengo dos listas en R: `list_1` y `list_2` los elementos de cada una de ellas son series de tiempo. Las series de tiempo en `list_1` pueden o no estar en `list_2`. Series de tiempo en las dos listas lucen de la siguiente forma:

```
2007-07-03 1270.9060
2007-07-04 1267.8440
2007-07-05 1269.7260
2007-07-06 1270.7180
2007-07-07 1270.6210
2007-07-08 1270.5230
2007-07-09 1272.6600
2007-07-10 1275.3270
2007-07-11 1269.2300
2007-07-12 1267.7230
2007-07-13 1271.5470
2007-07-14 1271.4500
2007-07-15 1271.3520
2007-07-16 1271.2550
2007-07-17 1269.3970
2007-07-18 1258.4610
2007-07-19 1259.3700
2007-07-20 1272.2220
2007-07-21 1272.1250
2007-07-22 1272.0270
2007-07-23 1279.5210
2007-07-24 1283.7750
2007-07-25 1292.8030
2007-07-26 1279.0540
```

Necesito dos cosas:

1. Identificar cuál serie de tiempo está en una lista y no en otra, para eso, usé este código:

   ```
   names1 = sort(names(list_1))
    names2 = sort(names(list_2))
    c(setdiff(names1,names2),setdiff(names2,names1))
   ```
2. Para los nombres de las series de tiempo que están en ambas listas, necesito identificar si las dos series de tiempo respectivas son idénticas. Para eso usé este código:

quantq = list()

```
for (i in names1) {
  if (i %in% names(2)) {
    quantq[i] = names(all(series_list_manual[[i]] != series_list_s3[[i]]))
  }
  }
```

Creé la lista `quantq` que esperaba que contenga los nombres de las series de tiempo que están en  `names1` que no son indénticas a su equivalente en `names2`, pero desafortunadamente parece no funcionar porque porque me da algo así:

```
   [1]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
  [19]   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36
  [37]   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54
  [55]   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72
  [73]   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90
  [91]   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108
 [109]  109  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119  120  121  122  123  124  125  126
 [127]  127  128  129  130  131  132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139  140  141  142  143  144
 [145]  145  146  147  148  149  150  151  152  153  154  155  156  157  158  159  160  161  162
```

Creo que el problema es que mi código toma solo una lista a la vez y muestra el número (posición) de las entradas que no son iguales en la serie de tiempo respectiva en la otra lista. Estoy en lo correcto?

Pueden ayudarme a crear una lista con los nombres de las series de tiempo que no son idénticas?

Aquí presento un pequeño subconjunto de las dos listas:: `ex1` para `list_1` y `ex2` para `list_2`:

```
ex1 = list(COP = structure(c(1877.5, 1892.5, 1910, 1912.4, 1901, 1902.5, 
1901, 1905.85, 1917, 1921), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946857600, 
946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 
947635200, 947721600, 947808000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L)), CLP = structure(c(528, 529.43, 530, 527, 524.55, 522.5, 
522.5, 519.53, 517.05, 515.67), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946857600, 
946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 
947635200, 947721600, 947808000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L)), CLF = structure(c(0.036074341203342, 0.0358335681613619, 
0.0360059735494465, 0.0358781557617286, 0.035702777866953, 0.0356677208908729, 
0.0355560203401352, 0.035958251000177, 0.035870302585323, 0.0357348617586791
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1080864000, 1081123200, 
1081209600, 1081296000, 1081382400, 1081728000, 1081814400, 1081900800, 
1081987200, 1082073600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL)))

ex2 = list(CLP = structure(c(528, 529.43, 530, 527, 524.55, 522.5, 
522.5, 519.53, 517.05, 515.67), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946857600, 
946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 
947635200, 947721600, 947808000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L)), CLF = structure(c(0.036074341203342, 0.0358335681613619, 
0.0360059735494465, 0.0358781557617286, 0.035702777866953, 0.0356677208908729, 
0.0355560203401352, 0.035958251000177, 0.035870302585323, 0.0357348617586791
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1080864000, 1081123200, 
1081209600, 1081296000, 1081382400, 1081728000, 1081814400, 1081900800, 
1081987200, 1082073600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL)), MXN = structure(c(9.505, 
9.5713, 9.571, 9.58, 9.565, 9.47, 9.5125, 9.522, 9.4875, 9.4503
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946857600, 946944000, 
947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 947635200, 
947721600, 947808000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L)), PEN = structure(c(3.52, 3.5205, 3.519, 3.509, 3.511, 3.509, 
3.508, 3.509, 3.5005, 3.4875), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946857600, 
946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 
947635200, 947721600, 947808000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu respuesta básicamente está bien, aunque te sugeriría una forma más concisa de resolverlo:

```
eq <- intersect(names(list_1), names(list_2))
eq[sapply(eq, FUN=function(x) {!identical(list_1[x], list_2[x])})]
```

Si la idea es buscar los elementos que coincidan entre las dos listas, es más directo ir a buscar estos elementos mediante `intersect()` justamente la intersección de los dos conjuntos. Luego simplemente con `sapply` "aplicamos" `identical()` solo sobre los elementos coincidentes.

Comment: Sí . Tu sugerencia es util. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Update: Creo que pude solucionar el problema. Esto es lo que intenté:

```
names1 = sort(names(list_1))  #Para obtener los nombres de las series de tiempo en list_1
names2 = sort(names(list_2))  #Para obtener los nombres de las series de tiempo en list_2
not_eq = c(setdiff(names1,names2),setdiff(names2,names1)) #Esto da los nombres de las series de tiempo que no están en la intersección de las listas.
(length(names1))
(length(names2))


quantq = list() #Creé una lista vacía para almacenar el nombre de las series de tiempo que no son idénticas en las dos listas


for (tik in names1){
  if (tik %in% names2 & !identical(list_1[[tik]], list_2[[tik]])){
    quantq[[tik]] = tik
    print(which(list_1[[tik]] != list_2[[tik]]))
   }else {
    print("Equal")
   }
  }

names(quantq)  #Para obtener los nombres de las series de tiempo desiguales
(length(names(quantq))) #Verificar que la cantidad de series de tiempo desiguales sea menor o igual que el total
```

¿Qué piensan ustedes? ¿Se puede mejorar?